# Open Windows Explorer to a network folder from a dotnet client

Tags: c#

I try to open Windows explorer to `\\aserver\d$` with C#. The AServer machine needs an other user, a user that does not necessarily have rights on the machine the code is running on.

I want the Windows explorer window to *show without asking the user for credentials* as I provide usr/pwd through code.

---

If I do `Process.Start( @"\\aserver\d$" )` Windows asks me for credentials.

I have tried `Process.Start( @"\\aserver\d$", username, password, domain )` but it returns an `Access is denied` exception. Changing the usr/pwd gives me a `The user name or password is incorrect` so I know I have the right usr/pwd/domain combination. I guess dotnet is trying to start a process "explorer.exe" with the other user which doesn't have rights on my machine.

I have tried playing around with `Process.Start( new ProcessStartInfo{...} )` but have not figured out the right combination.

Comment: Few things: yes, credentials you provide when you start a process are for local computer, not remote one (and you can't change this). However you may first map remote path to a local drive (programmatically). Second important thing: "\\aserver" is "\aserver", use vebatim @"\\aserver" instead

Comment: if you do a "net use \\server\\ipc$" and provide the credentials before you open the explorer this might work

Comment: You can import the dll "Mpr.Dll" and call extern method WNetUseConnection to map the drive first as Adriano mentioned. The method signature includes username and password.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thx. Fixed.

Comment: @Marged I have played with net use too; but then I didn't think of doing it in 2 steps, first `net use` and the `Process.Start`. Is there anything special to calling `net use`? - I had some problems I recall.

Comment: I often call `net use \\server\ipc$ /user:domain\user /persistent:no` to make certain that correct permissions are set and then call explorer on any of the drives of that server. Works flawlessly

Comment: @Marged I mean from c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which I am using which you can utilize to map a network drive programmatically:

```
public class NetworkSharedDrive
    {
        #region Consts
        const int RESOURCE_CONNECTED = 0x00000001;
        const int RESOURCE_GLOBALNET = 0x00000002;
        const int RESOURCE_REMEMBERED = 0x00000003;

        const int RESOURCETYPE_ANY = 0x00000000;
        const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 0x00000001;
        const int RESOURCETYPE_PRINT = 0x00000002;

        const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC = 0x00000000;
        const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN = 0x00000001;
        const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER = 0x00000002;
        const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE = 0x00000003;
        const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_FILE = 0x00000004;
        const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GROUP = 0x00000005;

        const int RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE = 0x00000001;
        const int RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER = 0x00000002;


        const int CONNECT_INTERACTIVE = 0x00000008;
        const int CONNECT_PROMPT = 0x00000010;
        const int CONNECT_REDIRECT = 0x00000080;
        const int CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE = 0x00000001;
        const int CONNECT_COMMANDLINE = 0x00000800;
        const int CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED = 0x00001000;

        const int CONNECT_LOCALDRIVE = 0x00000100;
        #endregion

        #region Errors
        const int NO_ERROR = 0;

        const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;
        const int ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED = 85;
        const int ERROR_BAD_DEVICE = 1200;
        const int ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME = 67;
        const int ERROR_BAD_PROVIDER = 1204;
        const int ERROR_CANCELLED = 1223;
        const int ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR = 1208;
        const int ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS = 487;
        const int ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87;
        const int ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD = 1216;
        const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;
        const int ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259;
        const int ERROR_NO_NET_OR_BAD_PATH = 1203;
        const int ERROR_NO_NETWORK = 1222;

        const int ERROR_BAD_PROFILE = 1206;
        const int ERROR_CANNOT_OPEN_PROFILE = 1205;
        const int ERROR_DEVICE_IN_USE = 2404;
        const int ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED = 2250;
        const int ERROR_OPEN_FILES = 2401;

        private struct ErrorClass
        {
            public int num;
            public string message;
            public ErrorClass(int num, string message)
            {
                this.num = num;
                this.message = message;
            }
        }

        private static ErrorClass[] ERROR_LIST = new ErrorClass[] {
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, "Error: Access Denied"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED, "Error: Already Assigned"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_BAD_DEVICE, "Error: Bad Device"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME, "Error: Bad Net Name"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_BAD_PROVIDER, "Error: Bad Provider"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_CANCELLED, "Error: Cancelled"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR, "Error: Extended Error"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS, "Error: Invalid Address"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, "Error: Invalid Parameter"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD, "Error: Invalid Password"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_MORE_DATA, "Error: More Data"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS, "Error: No More Items"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_NO_NET_OR_BAD_PATH, "Error: No Net Or Bad Path"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_NO_NETWORK, "Error: No Network"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_BAD_PROFILE, "Error: Bad Profile"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_CANNOT_OPEN_PROFILE, "Error: Cannot Open Profile"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_DEVICE_IN_USE, "Error: Device In Use"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR, "Error: Extended Error"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED, "Error: Not Connected"), 
        new ErrorClass(ERROR_OPEN_FILES, "Error: Open Files"), 
    };

        private static string getErrorForNumber(int errNum)
        {
            foreach (ErrorClass er in ERROR_LIST)
            {
                if (er.num == errNum) return er.message;
            }
            return "Error: Unknown, " + errNum;
        }
        #endregion

        [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
            IntPtr hwndOwner,
            NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
            string lpPassword,
            string lpUserID,
            int dwFlags,
            string lpAccessName,
            string lpBufferSize,
            string lpResult
            );

        [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(
            string lpName,
            int dwFlags,
            bool fForce
            );

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private class NETRESOURCE
        {
            public int dwScope = 0;
            public int dwType = 0;
            public int dwDisplayType = 0;
            public int dwUsage = 0;
            public string lpLocalName = "";
            public string lpRemoteName = "";
            public string lpComment = "";
            public string lpProvider = "";
        }


        public static string connectToRemote(string remoteUNC, string username, string password)
        {
            return connectToRemote(remoteUNC, username, password, false);
        }

        public static string connectToRemote(string remoteUNC, string username, string password, bool promptUser)
        {
            NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
            nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
            nr.lpRemoteName = remoteUNC;

            int ret;
            if (promptUser)
                ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, "", "", CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT, null, null, null);
            else
                ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);

            if (ret == NO_ERROR) return null;
            return getErrorForNumber(ret);
        }

        public static string disconnectRemote(string remoteUNC)
        {
            int ret = WNetCancelConnection2(remoteUNC, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, false);
            if (ret == NO_ERROR) return null;
            return getErrorForNumber(ret);
        }
    }
}
```